# C# datagridview adding extra items not showing up

Tags: c#, user-interface, datagridview, objectdatasource

I have a `DataGridView` and a `button`. On pressing this `button` it should add in a new row into the `DataGridView`. In order to do this I have the following code:

```
    List<NavigationInfo> navigationRules = new List<NavigationInfo>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        navigationRules.Add(new NavigationInfo());
        setDataSource(navigationRules);
    }


    public void setDataSource(List<NavigationInfo> data)
    {
        this.dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
        this.dataGridView2.Show();
        this.dataGridView2.Invalidate();
        this.dataGridView2.Update();
    }
```

Now when I click on this button the first time it correctly adds in a new row. If however I click on it a second time it does not show up. 
Breakpointing shows me that the `datasource` does actually receive extra items. They just don't show up.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: @mwisnicki I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [**refresh()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) once you update, also set the DataSource to null,

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = data;        
dataGridView2.update();
dataGridView2.refresh();
```

Comment: @Thijser It should work, did you set the datasource to null before setting the new values?

Comment: No I just set it, I even straight up copied over your code (except I capitalised the Update and Refresh)

Comment: @Thijser can you give me team viewer?

Comment: I prefer not, I also have a very limited data capacity right now. But I can upload some screenshots

Comment: @Thijser ok np:) add a debug window and check if the new items are added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123594/discussion-between-thijser-and-sajeetharan).